# PHP Twitter OAuth - I cannot authenticate my account

Tags: php, authentication, twitter, oauth

I am struggling whole day with implementation of Twitter authentication (with using OAuth), but I am already desperate, I am still getting the error message **Could not authenticate you.**, it's becoming my nightmare.

Here are my two files which I use for authentication:

**requestOauth.php**

```
session_start();
$basedir=dirname(__FILE__)."";  
include($basedir.'/config.php');
include_once( $basedir.'/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php' );

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);    
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

//$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
//$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $secret = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret']; 

switch ($connection->http_code) {
  case 200:

    $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($_SESSION['oauth_token'], FALSE);
    header('Location: ' . $url); 
    break;
  default:
    echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}
```

**index.php**

```
if(!isset($_GET['oauth_verifier'])){
    $link_redirect = '<a href="requestOauth.php">Login With Twitter</a>';
}
else
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['access_token'])){ 
        $oauth_token = $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token'];
        $oauth_token_secret = $_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'];
        $twitterRequest = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);

    } else {

        $twitterRequest = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret']);
        $accessToken = $twitterRequest->getAccessToken($_GET['oauth_verifier']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $accessToken;
        echo 'ACCESS TOKEN2: '.var_dump($_SESSION['access_token']);
    }

    $user_info = $twitterRequest->get('account/verify_credentials');
    if(isset($user_info->error))
    {
        echo $user_info->error;
        //header("location: requestOauth.php");
    }  else {
        var_dump($_GET);
    }
```

I am still getting the error **Could not authenticate you.** and already have no idea, where could be something wrong...

Could you please give me any help, how to figure out this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation, step 8](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION) you have to build another `TwitterOAuth` object after calling `getAccessToken` with the values you get from there.

In your case something like this could work:

```
$twitterRequest = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $accessToken['oauth_token'], $accessToken['oauth_token_secret']);
```